# Connecting VST.NET to NAudio

Tags: c#

Is there a simple bit of c# code to connect VST.NET to NAudio ASIO. I've tried to understand the examples but get lost in the code! I've copied over the Utility code and VST code from MidiVSTTest and can load up the vsti - just can't make it sound!

What I've got:
'''

```
        UtilityAudio.OpenAudio(AudioLibrary.NAudio, "Komplete Audio ASIO Driver");

        HostCommandStub hostCmdStub = new HostCommandStub();
        hostCmdStub.PluginCalled += new EventHandler<PluginCalledEventArgs>(HostCmdStub_PluginCalled);

        VstPluginContext ctx = VstPluginContext.Create("D:\\Reason\\Plugins\\arcade.dll", hostCmdStub);

        //plugin name
        string plName = ctx.PluginCommandStub.Commands.GetProductString();
        label1.Text = "Plugin Loaded = " + plName;

        // show plugin 
        Form1 plug = new Form1();
        plug.Text = plName;

        //get rect size for plugin
        var rect = new Rectangle();
        ctx.PluginCommandStub.Commands.EditorGetRect(out rect);

        plug.Width = rect.Width * 100 / 175 + 30;
        plug.Height = rect.Height * 100 / 175 + 70;

        ctx.PluginCommandStub.Commands.EditorOpen(plug.Handle);
        plug.ShowDialog();      
        
       //more sure how to get this line to work
        vst.StreamCall += vst_StreamCall;

        UtilityAudio.StartAudio();
```

'''

Please advise!

Comment: You need to call `ProcessReplacing()` on the plugin. The samples in the output buffer need to be converted from float [-1.0:1.0] to some type that ASIO/NAudio supports (for instance Int32). You may also have to interleave (left/right) channels into the target (NAudio) buffer. [2c]

Comment: That's the bit I'm stuck on! 
Anyway the demo project (MidiVstTest) doesn't run the samples at the correct speed (twice as fast?) for the Arcade vsti - so I've gone back to bassvst c++ which I've got working fine.